# Why there is no shutdown button while connected via RDP?

Tags: windows, rdp

Just wondering why there is no buttons for restart/shutdown/sleep/hibernate when i am connected via RDP? I would like to do some work and turn PC off or put it to sleep mode for power saving, because when i want to access target PC again i use [WOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN). Why should i use **shutdown.exe**?

[I have read](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/11/shutdown-restart-windows-remote-desktop-connection/) that Microsoft windows server has that buttons through RDP. What is the reason for disabling them in desktop version?

Comment: What version of windows server?

Comment: I can only assume because most users are idiots and need to be protected from themselves...

Comment: @Colyn1337 i said i have read in article and gave the link. Do not know and can not check any right now.

Comment: There are always workarounds. I haven't done it in a while but remember building icons for logoff, sleep, shutdown.  It must not have been hard because I don't remember how I did it.  This might be a job for Google.

Comment: @SDsolar i always just press `ALT+F4` and choose desired action ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for security and safety reasons. Prior to virtualisation if somebody remotely shutdown a server, they would need to gain physical access to the server room to power it back on (or use ILO or similar if available, but these technologies also became prevalent after this functionality was designed).

You can still access these options via "Windows Security", they're just obscured to prevent accidental and potentially troublesome shutdowns.

Answer (score 1):

Because someone complained to Microsoft that they had a 4 hour drive when they hit it by accident.

If you need one use Ctrl-Alt-End to get to the screen normally shown by Ctrl-Alt-Del and use the power button in the bottom right hand corner.